# Google Sheet Bespoke Reporting: Filter & Privacy

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, report, reporting, google-sheets-api

I seek an approach by which I can provide user a bespoke Google Sheet dashboard on the basis of some ID that is entered or transferred via URL.

To explain: as of now, raw data sits in a master Google Sheet and is processed and summarised in another Google Sheet dashboard that requires to enter an ID which acts as filter to the raw data so that the summary only presents insights associated with that particular ID and user - that works.

However, Each user should enter only their ID and see their summary. Right now all users have access to the same public Sheet and the possibility of parallel access is problematic.

How may I generate individual Sheets (one per user) that is based on a template?
Is this possible with default functionality, or Apps Script? Any advice is highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You would be better off creating an Apps Script Web App.  It seems that you already have a dashboard.  Is that dashboard made with HTML?  If so, you could probably reuse some of that in the Web App.  Multiple people can have the same Web App open without the issue of one user seeing anything from another user.  Each open instance will be unique that that person.  To create a Web App, use a "stand alone" Apps Script file.  Right now the Apps Script code may be "bound" to your spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks Sandy! Can you elaborate on that please: How would that Apps Script look like? Currently the dashboard is just Google Sheet asking for an ID by which it filters the underlying data. Would I have to build a dashboard in Apps Script, is there an easy way to build this using the Google Sheet UI and mimic/pass that on to the Web App dashboard? Thanks again!

Comment: For what I'm proposing, you would need to use HTML, client side JavaScript and CSS.  You might need to learn how to create a table in HTML to list the results.  You could use something like Awesome Tables.  The following is a link to the Apps Script documentation for Web Apps: [Link - Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Thanks again Sandy! I can create a table in HTML, though output would also have to include charts (Awesome Table doesn't offer that). I think the key challenge to solve here is: data-query -> row-level filtered data -> output as user-instance. How to build the mediating proxy and generate a user-instance Google Sheet dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

This is one option you can try, you can get the email ID of the user who opens the google spreadsheet like so:

```
function onOpen(e) {

  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui.alert(email)
  //doSomethingSpecificBasedOnEmail(email) call function that fliters data based on email ID
}
```

Note: There are few nuances to using Session.getEffectiveUser(). Based on permission and security setting, it can give you a blank user/email.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()

Second Option: 
If email ID is not an option and since you are ok with users entering an ID to access the data. This code will ask for an ID and create a copy of sheet called template and also set the value of A1 as the ID. The sheet can then use the ID to get ID specific data and make plots.

```
function onOpen(){
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.prompt('Get ID:');

 // Process the user's response.
 if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
   var id =  response.getResponseText();
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   var lookupSheet = ss.getSheetByName(id)
   if(lookupSheet == null){
     var template = ss.getSheetByName("Template")
     var newSheet = template.copyTo(ss)
     newSheet.setName(id)
     newSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(id)
     newSheet.activate()
   } else
   {
    lookupSheet.activate 
   }
 } else {
   Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
 }
}
```

An example of this can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPHUGKi7u9jJVc-3xCaYlrZ8kaHWvpl6gPZxUL1g32Y/edit?usp=sharing

Note: People can see each others sheet though, which I assume based on your post is not an issue. However, if that is not the case the best option is to use google  Web App script.

Comment: So that would require all users to have an Email address in the same domain or by Google? If so, then it limits what I seek to achieve. Other ideas?

Comment: Well updated the answer with a new method, hope that works out better